# NSClient++ FAIL on Windows 2008 R2 -- PDHCollector.cpp(215) Failed to query performance counters

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, monitoring, nagios, nsclient++

I am attempting to monitor windows server 2008 r2 x64 Enterprise with Nagios.

When I test/install the nsclientI get the following error:

```
PDHCollector.cpp(215) Failed to query performance counters: \Processor(_total)\% Processor Time: PdhGetFormattedCounterValue failed: A counter with a negative denominator value was detected.   (800007D6)
```

Has anyone else encountered the same issue and / or resolved it, found a work around?

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be an issue with Windows WBEM corruption.  Take a look at this conversation thread that recommends The wbem repository:  http://www.nsclient.org/nscp/discussion/message/2434

Comment: Care to comment on why the down vote?